# Image Upload by Jquery Form and PHP

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on an Image upload page. The upload works, but whenever i clicked the submit, it will go to the php page. I have returned false and set preventDefaut. Is there a way to stop it from going to php page?

my html code

```
 <form action="imageupload.php" method="post" id="image_form"enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="update_image" name="file" type="file" maxlength="40">
     <input id ="image_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

my js code

```
var options = { 
        target:   "#output",   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
       // beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmit,  // pre-submit callback 
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
    }; 

 $("#image_form").submit(function(e) { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);  //Ajax Submit form            
        // return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation
        e.preventDefault();
        return false; 
    });
```

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: Just move the file?  What's the problem here?

Comment: i figured that out  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cant really tell without seeing your code but I think you are looking for [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
move_uploaded_file($file,$newloc)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
$path = '/path/to/files/';
$filename = 'name_you_want_to_give_upload';

$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path . $filename);
```

Ref: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_move_uploaded_file.asp)

good luck!

Comment: Moving the uploaded file is impossible? I don't think so. Is this answer really intended for this question?